# Is there a tool to modify HTTP packet on the fly?

Tags: http, tcpip, packet-injection

Wireshark is good, but it doesn't allow you to change the content of the packet.

Is there a tool to do this job?

Comment: This StackOverflow question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260757/packet-mangling-utilities-besides-iptables

Answer (score 2):

Try fiddler

From http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ - 
"Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data."

Comment: Does it allows you to modify the data?

Comment: Yes, you can change the data.  Here are some examples: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp

Comment: It modified the data within a browser,how to do it without involving a browser?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Firefox addon called [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/?src=search) that can accomplish this.